# Populating a vector with numbers and conditions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, discrete-mathematics

Working on a business class assignment where we're using Excel to solve a problem with the following setup and conditions, but I wanted to find solutions by writing some code in C++ which is what I'm most familiar from some school courses.

We have 4 stores where we need to invest 10 million dollars. The main conditions are:

> 1. It is necessary to invest at least 1mil per store.
> 2. The investments in the 4 stores must total 10 million.
> 3. Following the rules above, the most one can invest in a single store is 7 million

Each store has its own unique return of investment percentages based off the amount of money invested per store.
In other words, there is a large number of combinations that can be obtained by investing in each store. Repetition of numbers does not matter as long as the total is 10 per combination, but the order of the numbers does matter.

If my math is right, the total number of combinations is 7^4 = 2401, but the number of working solutions 
is lesser due to the condition that each combination must equal 10 as a sum.

What I'm trying to do in C++ is use loops to populate each row with 4 numbers such that their sum equals 10 (millions), for example:

> 7  1   1   1
>
> 1  7   1   1
>
> 1  1   7   1
>
> 1  1   1   7
>
> 6  2   1   1
>
> 6  1   2   1
>
> 6  1   1   2
>
> 5  3   1   1
>
> 5  1   3   1
>
> 5  1   1   3
>
> 5  1   2   2
>
> 5  2   1   2
>
> 5  2   2   1

I'd appreciate advice on how to tackle this. Still not quite sure if using loops is a good idea whilst using an array (2D Array/Vector perhaps?) I've a vague idea that maybe recursive functions would facilitate a solution.

Thanks for taking some time to read, I appreciate any and all advice for coming up with solutions.

Edit: 
Here's some code I worked on to just get 50 rows of numbers randomized. Still have to implement the conditions where valid row combinations must be the sum total of 10 between the 4;

```
int main(){
    const int rows = 50;
    int values[rows][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
            values[i][j]= (rand() % 7 + 1);
            cout << values[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does each investment need to be divisible by $1 million? What's the smallest quantum of investment?

Comment: The smallest quantity is 1 (in millions) per store. We're not really dealing with fractions of numbers since we'll be multiplying each quantity times a separate table of fixed percentages of investments, but that is a separate problem.

Comment: I get that the smallest quantity is 1 million, but is it possible to invest $1,000,001 in a store? Is it possible to invest $1,100,000 in a store?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code?

Comment: Ah ok, the answer is no. Its either invest a whole 1 milllion, or 2,3... max 7. You get the idea.

Comment: Small update, added some code I began working with.

Comment: Don't randomize. The naive, first order solution is to iterate on the first item. Then, depending on the current value of the first item, iterate over all possible values of the second item. Then, depending on the current values of the first and second items, iterate over all possible values of the third item. The fourth item is left as an exercise to the reader. If you randomize you have the possibility to miss items.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this recursively. For each level, you have:

1. A target sum
2. The number of elements in that level
3. The minimum value each individual element can have

First, we determine our return type. What's your final output? Looks like a vector of vectors to me. So our recursive function will return a the same.

Second, we determine the result of our degenerate case (at the "bottom" of the recursion), when the number of elements in this level is 1.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>> recursive_combinations(std::size_t sum, std::size_t min_val, std::size_t num_elements)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>> result {};
    if (num_elements == 1)
    {
        result.push_back(std::vector<std::size_t>{sum});
        return result;
    }

    ...non-degenerate case goes here...

    return result;
}
```

Next, we determine what happens when this level has more than 1 element in it. Split the sum into all possible pairs of the "first" element and the "remaining" group. e.g., if we have a target `sum` of 5, 3 `num_elements`, and a `min_val` of 1, we'd generate the pairs `{1,4}`, `{2,3}`, and `{3,2}`, where the first number in each pair is for the first element, and the second number in each pair is the remaining sum left over for the remaining group.

Recursively call the `recursive_combinations` function using this second number as the new `sum`, and `num_elements - 1` as the new `num_elements` to find the vector of vectors for the remaining group, and for each vector in the return vector, append the first element from the above set.